# How is a variable set in powershell.exe without interaction?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a very strange thing happening on my Windows machine.

Regardless of if I load my `$profile` or not, a variable called `$item` is set immediately when starting `powershell.exe`.

I've performed the following:

- used the `-noprofile` swtich during an `powershell.exe` invocation.
- reviewed all DLLs loaded by `powershell.exe`, and verified no DLLs are side loading via `AppInit_DLLs` keys.
- I've copied a version of `powershell.exe` from another machine where the issue isn't happening.
- I've attempted as another user and the value persists in the process owned by that user.
- I've enumed the `functions:` PSdrive
- I've reviewed env vars in process explorer.
- I've reviewed all profiles (listed in `$profile | select *`)

How is possible that `$item` can be set immediately upon starting `powershell.exe`?

Comment: @brandeded, point of note, alongside 'Matt Cargile's helpful answer', thouh you did not mention other stuff in your environment, i.e., the 'Sentinel One XDR', the thing that was mentioned.  Note that powershell.exe/powershell_ise.exe and pwsh.exe are not PowerShell. So, copying these .exe from one machine or the other is a false flag. They are just shells constructed to run/dev Powershell code. One can write their own PC shell if they so choose to. Thus, one can run PS code without ever using those. Lastly, when you/some service uses PS stuff, ```$/$item``` get populated. Get-Variable to see.

Comment: ------------> ✅

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue with *Sentinel One* XDR ( e.g. S1) on version *22.1.2.217*. They load code into the session and pollute the global variable namespace. You can turn on [Powershell logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logging_windows?view=powershell-7.3) in Windows to see all the code. I *think* the feature is called *agent.deepVisibility.scripts.powershell* which can be found running `SentinelCtl configure` command line application as *Administrator*. Below is an excerpt for enabling the logging.

> To enable automatic transcription, enable the Turn on PowerShell Script Block Logging feature in Group Policy through Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows PowerShell.

[This issue](https://github.com/adamcysec/SentinelOne-PowerSploit-Indicators/issues/1) on *Github* details the code. Additionally, general information about the S1 scripts are in this repo as well. Thirdly, a trickle of information can be found in [this](https://gist.github.com/keyboardcrunch/6c2451815eb48c42bc3efbc01a809a9d?permalink_comment_id=4295910#gistcomment-4295910) *Github* comment which links off to a *Twitter* thread. Below is the applicable code that tarnishes the user's variable namespace.

```
$local:Po_wer_Spl_oit_Indicators = (
    ("{0}{5}{4}{2}{3}{1}" -f 'Inv','ion','nje','ct','I','oke-Dll'),
    ("{6}{2}{3}{8}{1}{7}{5}{0}{4}" -f 'o','eP','nvoke-','Reflect','n','ecti','I','EInj','iv'),
    ("{1}{0}{3}{2}"-f'v','In','lcode','oke-Shel'),
    ("{0}{2}{3}{1}" -f'Invoke-','ommand','W','miC'),
    ("{5}{1}{3}{2}{4}{0}" -f 'd','t-E','a','ncodedComm','n','Ou'),
    ("{4}{0}{2}{3}{1}" -f 'ut-C','l','ompre','ssedDl','O'),
    ("{2}{3}{4}{1}{0}" -f't','p','Out-Encrypted','Sc','ri'),
    ("{0}{2}{3}{1}"-f 'Rem','t','ove-Comm','en'),
    ("{0}{3}{7}{6}{2}{4}{5}{1}"-f'New','ion','te','-User','n','ceOpt','is','Pers'),
    ("{3}{2}{5}{1}{0}{4}" -f'eOpt','istenc','w-Elevated','Ne','ion','Pers'),
    ("{2}{3}{0}{1}{4}"-f 'is','te','Ad','d-Pers','nce'),
    ("{0}{3}{2}{1}" -f'Install-','P','S','S'),
    ("{4}{0}{3}{2}{5}{1}" -f 't-S','s','ka','ecurityPac','Ge','ge'),
    ("{3}{2}{1}{0}"-f 'gnature','-AVSi','ind','F'),
    ("{6}{2}{3}{1}{0}{5}{4}"-f 'u','ip','voke-T','okenMan','ion','lat','In'),
    ("{0}{3}{2}{4}{5}{1}" -f'In','n','oke-C','v','re','dentialInjectio'),
    ("{1}{2}{0}{3}{4}" -f'Nin','I','nvoke-','jaCop','y'),
    ("{2}{0}{1}" -f'Mimika','tz','Invoke-'),
    ("{1}{2}{3}{0}" -f'rokes','Get','-Ke','yst'),
    ("{2}{4}{1}{3}{0}"-f'ord','PPP','Get','assw','-G'),
    ("{3}{2}{1}{0}" -f'on','log','GPPAuto','Get-'),
    ("{3}{1}{5}{0}{2}{4}"-f 'cr','d','e','Get-Time','enshot','S'),
    ("{2}{4}{0}{1}{5}{3}"-f'lumeS','had','N','y','ew-Vo','owCop'),
    ("{1}{0}{3}{2}"-f '-VolumeShad','Get','py','owCo'),
    ("{1}{2}{3}{5}{4}{0}"-f 'y','Mount-Vol','umeShad','o','op','wC'),
    ("{2}{3}{4}{1}{0}{5}"-f 'wCop','eShado','Remo','ve-','Volum','y'),
    ("{2}{3}{4}{0}{1}{5}"-f'i','a','Get-VaultC','red','ent','l'),
    ("{1}{3}{2}{0}"-f'p','Out-M','um','inid'),
    ("{4}{1}{2}{0}{3}" -f 'neAudi','et-Mi','cropho','o','G'),
    ("{3}{5}{2}{6}{0}{1}{4}"-f'oot','Rec','te','S','ord','et-Mas','rB'),
    ("{0}{2}{1}{3}"-f 'Set-Crit','calP','i','rocess'),
    ("{2}{0}{1}{3}"-f 'oke','-Po','Inv','rtscan'),
    ("{1}{3}{2}{0}"-f 'ttpStatus','G','H','et-'),
    ("{2}{3}{1}{0}"-f'DnsLookup','-Reverse','Invo','ke'),
    ("{1}{3}{2}{0}" -f'oup','Get-Pro','r','cessTokenG'),
    ("{2}{0}{1}"-f 'et-Syst','em','G'),
    ("{0}{4}{3}{2}{1}" -f'Invok','oast','er','b','e-Ker')
)
foreach ($item in $local:Po_wer_Spl_oit_Indicators) {
        Set-PSBreakpoint -Command $item -Action { <#sentinelbreakpoints#> . {
    $local:PreviousErrCount = $error.count
    try { '' | out-file ':::::\windows\sentinel\8' } catch {}
    while ($PreviousErrCount -ne $error.count) {
        $error.remove($error[0])
    }
    Remove-Variable PreviousErrCount -Scope local -Confirm:$false -WhatIf:$false} } | Out-Null
};
```

Below is some code if you want to fully clean up your session of their meddling. They hook into `$PSDefaultParameterValues` and slow down the session. Further, S1 breaks piping usage for `Get-PSBreakpoint | Remove-PSBreakpoint`.

```
# VS Code doesn't have the same issue for some reason.
if ($PSVersionTable.PSEdition -eq 'Desktop' -and $env:TERM_PROGRAM -ne 'vscode') {
    # Addition of breakpoints slow down the session. Calling fully qualified function to avoid using function override.
    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Get-PSBreakpoint | Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Remove-PSBreakpoint
    # Software doesn't clean up these variables
    Remove-Variable -Name 'item', 'Po_wer_Spl_oit_Indicators' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    # Software overrides and hooks into these functions and breaks things. For instance, `gbp | rbp` doesn't work
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\Get-PSBreakpoint' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\New-Object' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\Set-ExecutionPolicy' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\Remove-PSBreakpoint' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\Disable-PSBreakpoint' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\Enable-PSBreakpoint' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    # Other functions added that aren't needed
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\Disable-PSBreakpoint_Hook' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\Enable-PSBreakpoint_Hook' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\Get-PSBreakpoint_Hook' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\New-Object_Hook' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\Remove-PSBreakpoint_Hook' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
    Remove-Item -Path 'Function:\Set-ExecutionPolicy_Hook' -ErrorAction 'Ignore'
}
```

#### UPDATE 1:

As of some iteration of version *23* of the *Sentinel One* agent, the entire bootstrap script seems to have been removed. The breakpoints are no longer seen when one runs `microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Get-PSBreakpoint` nor are the aforementioned functions created.

Comment: Great work, Matt!  Thank you.